# MYSQL Summing Fields within a column for given Timestamp

Tags: mysql

Essentially I’m trying to add some fields from a table and reproduce another table with no luck.

The initial table looks like;

```
ID   STATUS       Min       Max     Mean    TimeStamp   
1   Motor1-ON     10        20       15     12/01/2013 05:00 
2   Motor1-OFF     5        7         6     12/01/2013 05:00
3   Motor1- HOLD   1        3         2     12/01/2013 05:00 
4   Motor2-ON      8        12       10     12/01/2013 05:00 
5   Motor2-OFF     4        6         5     12/01/2013 05:00
6   Motor2-HOLD    1        5         3     12/01/2013 05:00

7   Motor1-ON     11       21        16     12/01/2013 05:10
8   Motor1-OFF     5        7         6     12/01/2013 05:10
9   Motor1- HOLD   1        3         2     12/01/2013 05:10
10  Motor2-ON      9       10        9.5    12/01/2013 05:10
11  Motor2-OFF     5        7         6     12/01/2013 05:10
12  Motor2-HOLD    1        5         3     12/01/2013 05:10
.     .            .        .         .           .
.     .            .        .         .           .
.     .            .        .         .           .
```

Status is given on two types:  Motor 1 and Motor 2 for a timestamp that increments every 10 minutes.
I’m trying to create a new table based on the first table  so to add the 3 statuses of Motor 1 and Motor2 for each timestamp .The table I’m trying to achieve (with no luck so far) should look like;

```
Timestamp        Total_ON   Total_ON    Total_ON    Total_OFF    Total_OFF    Total_OFF
                    _Min      _Max        _Mean       _Min        _Max         _Mean

12/01/2013 05:00     18        32          35          9           13            11
12/01/2013 05:10     20        31         25.5         10          14            12
    .                 .             .                    .          .             . 
    .                 .             .                    .          .             .
```

(The table continues on to include Total_Hold_Min, Total_Hold_Max, Total_Hold_Mean)

Where

```
Total_ON_Min = Motor 1_ON  Min +  Motor 2_ON Min (For its given Timestamp)

Total_ON_Max = Motor1_ON Max + Motor2_OFF Max (For its given Timestamp)

Total_ON_Mean =  Motor1_ON Mean + Motor2_OFF Mean (For its given Timestamp)
```

Etc….

Can anyone offer any advice on the correct mysql statements I should be looking at to achieve this. I’ve been trying to implement CrossTab with no success .Using a select statement and sum aggregate function to calculate individual totals for motor1 and motor 2 separately is no problem but adding the two fields within each timestamp I’m having no success

Any thoughts or related links much appreciated as I'm trying to build on my knowledge base

I am new to mysql

Thanks

Additional Info:

The Motor status is very much independent and static so I can't break it down. The pivot table loses the flexibility I need as pointed out. I came up with a part solution based on the given ideas which works for a total of Min.

```
SELECT

`timestamp`,

status,

SUM(Min) AS `Total_ON_MIN` FROM Tablename where Status IN('Motor1_on','Motor2_on')
FROM table

GROUP BY `timestamp`
```

I'm falling short though on using this methodology to bring in 'Total_Max_ON' etc. With error on Group by timestamp.

```
SELECT
    `timestamp`,
     status,

(SELECT SUM(Min) AS `Total_ON_MIN` FROM Tablename where Status IN('Motor1_on','Motor2_on')),

(SELECT SUM(Max) AS `Total_ON_MAX` FROM Tablename where Status IN('Motor1_on','Motor2_on')),

(SELECT SUM(Mean) AS `Total_ON_MEAN` FROM Tablename where Status IN('Motor1_on','Motor2_on'))

GROUP BY `timestamp`
```

Any thoughts for further direction.Cheers

Comment: Search for details on how to pivot data in MySQL and then have a go; come back and ask for help if you're stuck.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I'll dig into Pivot Data and see where it goes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should strongly consider splitting motor identifier (i.e. Motor 1, Motor 2) and status indicator (on/off/hold) into two separate fields.

You could then easily query like

```
SELECT
    `timestamp`,
    SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'ON' THEN Min ELSE 0 END CASE) AS `ON_Min`,
    SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'ON' THEN Max ELSE 0 END CASE) AS `ON_Max`,
    SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'ON' THEN Mean ELSE 0 END CASE) AS `ON_Mean`,
    SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'OFF' THEN Min ELSE 0 END CASE) AS `OFF_Min`,
    SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'OFF' THEN Max ELSE 0 END CASE) AS `OFF_Max`,
    SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'OFF' THEN Mean ELSE 0 END CASE) AS `OFF_Mean`
FROM table
GROUP BY `timestamp`
ORDER BY `timestamp` ASC
```

OR if you really don't need a pivot you could do

```
SELECT
    `timestamp`,
    status,
    SUM(Min) AS `Min_Sum`,
    SUM(Max) AS `Max_Sum`,
    SUM(Mean) AS `Mean_Sum`
FROM table
GROUP BY `timestamp`, status
ORDER BY `timestamp` ASC, status ASC
```

OR if you need to break down by motor

```
SELECT
    `timestamp`,
    motor,
    status,
    SUM(Min) AS `Min_Sum`,
    SUM(Max) AS `Max_Sum`,
    SUM(Mean) AS `Mean_Sum`
FROM table
GROUP BY `timestamp`, motor, status
ORDER BY `timestamp` ASC, motor ASC, status ASC
```

You see you get a lot more flexibility to query if you break up the motor and status.

If you absolutely can't break up status into Motor and status, then I might do the following:

```
SELECT
    `timestamp`,
    SUM(CASE WHEN status LIKE '%ON' THEN Min ELSE 0 END CASE) AS `ON_Min`,
    SUM(CASE WHEN status LIKE '%ON' THEN Max ELSE 0 END CASE) AS `ON_Max`,
    SUM(CASE WHEN status LIKE '%ON' THEN Mean ELSE 0 END CASE) AS `ON_Mean`,
    SUM(CASE WHEN status LIKE '%OFF' THEN Min ELSE 0 END CASE) AS `OFF_Min`,
    SUM(CASE WHEN status LIKE '%OFF' THEN Max ELSE 0 END CASE) AS `OFF_Max`,
    SUM(CASE WHEN status LIKE '%OFF' THEN Mean ELSE 0 END CASE) AS `OFF_Mean`
FROM table
GROUP BY `timestamp`
ORDER BY `timestamp` ASC
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. The motor status pretty much can't be broken down. I posted additional info on a part solution based on your ideas Mike. I'm falling short on completion though. Any further direction is appreciated.

Comment: Cheers .That makes more sense.Works as expected.Thanks for the input.